# How can I create a GUI and react to Cocoa events programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I found out how to create a window in Cocoa programmatically but can't figure out how to react to events. The window is not reacting to a Quit request or button click.

I tried adding the following controller and used setDelegate/setTarget without luck:

```
    @interface AppController : NSObject {
    }
    - (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
    @end

    @implementation AppController
    - (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
    {
        printf("Button clicked!\n");
    }
    @end

    int main(int argc, char **args){
        NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

        AppController *controller = [[AppController alloc] init];

>       [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:controller];
        NSWindow* window  = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask
                                            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                            defer:NO];
        [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];

        NSButton *button = [ [ NSButton alloc ] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect( 30.0, 20.0, 80.0, 50.0 ) ];
        [ button setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
        [ button setTitle: @"Click" ];
>       [ button setAction:@selector(doSomething:)];
>       [ button setTarget:controller];
        [ [ window contentView ] addSubview: button ];

        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place?  You should generally use Interface Builder to create your application's human interface.

Comment: I'm creating a port of another GUI toolkit.

Comment: @Chris: one reason for me to look into programmatic GUI creation is that i load a number of objects with properties from a file, and i have to make all the properties editable without knowing at compile time how many there are, how they are labelled and what datatype they are (float, int, NSString, NSPoint, ...). Although i think i only need to fill an empty dummy view since other UI elements are static.

Comment: @Chris Hanson:  There are MANY reasons to build user interfaces programmatically. To think one should always use Interface Builder is naive. If only I could vote down this inexperienced comment.

Comment: @ctpenrose: A comment can't be inexperienced, only a person can. And I'm not inexperienced with Cocoa or Objective-C, or with Mac development for many years before Apple bought NeXT. I've seen, time and again, that developers used to other toolkits (Windows/Java) immediately try to implement their entire UI in code like the OP's question. As I said *in general* you shouldn't do that, you should just use IB. In cases where it's needed, use code, but be smart about it, don't knee-jerk to it because other platforms' tools suck.

Comment: Also, what I've seen in my career is that trying to port one toolkit to run atop another just results in poor applications, because there can be a significant impedance mismatch between toolkits. Abstract your model and model-controller code out, and create custom UI for each platform. Your users will thank you for it, and your application will have a better architecture besides.

Comment: From what I have experienced reading developer forums, is that comments which try to guess the intention of the developer rather than answer the question, often to fail to add value to the discussion.

Comment: He didn't "guess", he asked why the OP wanted to do this in the first place. I agree with Chris, that IB is far faster, easier to maintain, than attempting to create everything in code. However, I also have a case where I have to do things "from scratch". I would use IB if I could, but I'm doing ObjC on Linux... and frankly Gorm is awful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to invoke -[NSApplication run] instead of -[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]. The reason should be clear if you look at the basic structure of the method:

```
- (void)run
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [self finishLaunching];

    shouldKeepRunning = YES;
    do
    {
        [pool release];
        pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSEvent *event =
            [self
                nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]
                inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                dequeue:YES];

        [self sendEvent:event];
        [self updateWindows];
    } while (shouldKeepRunning);

    [pool release];
}
```

NSApplication encapsulates a lot about how to get an event, how to dispatch them and how to update windows.

Comment: Nice, thanks. That solves my problem. Where did you get this source code from?

So it seems that I can even implement my own run loop somewhere and use this provided logic.

Comment: I created this code for my blog post: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/demystifying-nsapplication-by.html

I reconstructed this method by reading the documentation for NSApplication closely and guessing at all implied steps until it worked.

Answer (score 2):

> I found out how to create a window in Cocoa programmatically …

Why? Why not just make a nib?

> The window is not reacting to a Quit request or button click.

How would you quit a window? This isn't Windows 3; applications can have multiple windows on Mac OS X. As such, closing a window and quitting an application are separate actions.

> [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

Except in rare circumstances, running the run loop is NSApplication's job, and you should leave that to it. Use `NSApplicationMain` or `-[NSApplication run]` to tell the application to run.

Comment: - I'm porting another GUI toolkit (written in another programming language) to the Mac. So the GUI is very dynamic and I don't think there's a point in having a NIB file.
- Quit: Through the application menu
- Calling run on the application does the trick, thanks!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. I think Matt Gallagher answered it already, but if you want to go further with this, you'll have to delve into Apple's [event-handling documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html). Bear in mind that doing everything programmatically will require a solid understanding of [cocoa fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I spent an entire day looking for answers to the GUI and Menu portion of this question. There are not that many current, concise answers out there to the question. So after solving it for myself, I posted an answer which addresses this on Stack here: [Cocoa GUI Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21987979/754494). I add a referral to it here to help community members who are digging around for the same answers.