# Cocoa get main window

Tags: cocoa, mainwindow

I want to create 3 windows like this:

```
NSWindow *win1 = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect1
                                             styleMask:uiStyle
                                               backing:backingStoreStyle
                                                 defer:NO];
```

and make one of them the main window, then get the main window, but I always get `nil`.

```
[win1 makeKeyAndOrderFront:win1];
[win2 makeKeyAndOrderFront:win2];
[win3 makeKeyAndOrderFront:win3];
[win2 makeMainWindow];
```

And all of these are nil:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [app mainWindow]);
NSLog(@"%@", [win1 isMainWindow]);
NSLog(@"%@", [win2 isMainWindow]);
NSLog(@"%@", [win3 isMainWindow]);
```

Comment: Downvoter; please explain why you downvoted.  This looks like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: You shouldn't be logging the result of `[NSWindow isMainWindow]` using the format `%@` as it's a `BOOL`, not an object.  Use format `%d` or `%u` instead.

Comment: I just log the result information here, yes %d or %u is better, but I also get the 0, so I ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. It does return an instantiated NSWindow object. I didn't get nil at all. Can you please post more context to code snippet?

Secondly, it is far easier and manageable to create window in IB. Thirdly, check `- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow` before passing it the message `makeMainWindow`.

If you want to create custom windows programaticaly, I would suggest create a Window in MainMenu.xib. Get it's IBOutlet, for example `window`. Then create your windows win1, win2 etc and add then as child windows to your `window` using `addChildWindow`.

Comment: @ Andrew-Dufresne Hi, how you get the object? is it win2? Here I want to code these in command-line, and test the mainwindow. Thanks for comments.

Comment: @Frank See this [SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/656129/177116). It has the code you need to create NSWindow programmatically.