# Either AppDelgate is called or ViewController is

Tags: objective-c, macos, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I am wanting **both** my AppDelegate and my ViewController to be called on startup (as expected).

When only the ViewController is called:

#### main.c

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

When the AppDelegate is called and the view controller is not.

#### main.c

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSArray *tl;
    NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewController" owner:application topLevelObjects:&tl];
    
    AppDelegate *applicationDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];      // Instantiate App  delegate
    [application setDelegate:applicationDelegate];                      // Assign delegate to the NSApplication
    [application run];                                                  // Call the Apps Run method
    
    return 0;       // App Never gets here.
}
```

I think my problem is that with the second attempt of the **main.c** is that...

```
NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewController" owner:application topLevelObjects:&tl];
```

is not working as expected. Where do I actually set the 'Nib' in the IB?

What is wrong?

Comment: Please read an introduction to Cocoa programming.

Comment: app will only get to return point only if you call terminate on default runloop (which you have triggered on previous line).  Default app runloop is like a while (true) {shouldIDoSomething}. And give a brief look https://github.com/drichardson/examples/blob/master/NiblessCocoaApp/main.m You will have idea how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You've got this kind of confused.... you should look more closely at my other answer over here: [Other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694510/programatically-create-initial-window-of-cocoa-app-os-x/21987979#21987979)

Your first main.c example is completely wrong. Your second main.c, which is closer to the example I gave is better, but you're calling **viewController** where you should be referencing the MainMenu nib, as in my example.

This line is wrong:

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewController" owner:application topLevelObjects:&tl];
```

put the NIB name there... that's why the method argument is called "loadNibNamed" :)- and get rid of @"ViewController".

Now if you are trying to call a full blown nib, then you don't really need my example. That was designed for people who are really trying to be almost completely programmatic.